# Build failed with an exception while using image_picker

Tags: flutter

I can't run my application when I add image_picker to my pubspec.yaml.

The application builds with no error when i remove the image_picker dependency.
I haven't even written code to use the dependency and the application won't build. I have the following dependencies on my pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker:
  http:
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.0.3+3
  geolocator:
```

When I try to build the application an error is thrown in the debug console.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\Development\FlutterApps\raktadaan\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:101: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  C:\Development\FlutterApps\raktadaan\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:101: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
      error: failed linking references.
      Command: C:\Users\timsi\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\7fc18efb2479d26a43577e12be5a39f3\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
              C:\Users\timsi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
              --manifest\
              C:\Development\FlutterApps\raktadaan\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
              -o\
              C:\Development\FlutterApps\raktadaan\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
              -R\
              @C:\Development\FlutterApps\raktadaan\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
              --auto-add-overlay\
              --java\
              C:\Development\FlutterApps\raktadaan\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
              --custom-package\
              com.bimsina.raktadaan\
              -0\
              apk\
              --output-text-symbols\
              C:\Development\FlutterApps\raktadaan\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
              --no-version-vectors
      Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    BUILD FAILED in 57s
    Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
    Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Set `compileSdkVersion 28` in `app/build.gradle`

Comment: I am the same issue and changing compilSdkVersion to 28 doesn't work

Comment: @UlugToprak changing the compileSdkVersion to 28 didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin was updated from the deprecated Android support libraries to AndroidX. use AndroidX to migrate app. Alternatively, use this plugin pinned to the version major 0.4.12.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: ^0.4.12
```

See issued: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27194